# c++ printing the contents of a string

Tags: c++, string

Could somebody explain to me why I cannot print the string `hexaDeciNum` in the code below by using `cout << hexaDeciNum` instead I have to loop through the characters like a c char array? I realise that this is a basic question apologies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

string solution(string &S){

    int n = stoi(S);
    int answer = 0;

    // char array to store hexadecimal number
    string hexaDeciNum;

    // counter for hexadecimal number array
    int i = 0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        // temporary variable to store remainder
        int temp  = 0;

        // storing remainder in temp variable.
        temp = n % 16;

        // check if temp < 10
        if(temp < 10)
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 48;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 55;
            i++;
        }

        n = n/16;
    }


    // printing hexadecimal number array in reverse order
    for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
        //cout << hexaDeciNum[j] << "\n";

        if (hexaDeciNum[j] == 'A' or hexaDeciNum[j]=='B' or
                    hexaDeciNum[j] == 'C' or hexaDeciNum[j] == 'D' or
                    hexaDeciNum[j] == 'E' or hexaDeciNum[j] == 'F' or
                    hexaDeciNum[j] == '1' or hexaDeciNum[j] == '0' ) {
                    answer = 1;
                }


}

    if (answer == 1){
        return hexaDeciNum;
    }
    else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}


int main() {

    string word = "257";

    cout <<  solution(word);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: why do you think you have to do that? What happens when you try? Indeed you dont need an explicit loop to print a string

Comment: There are a lot of problems here aside from the output thing. Notably you should not use the brackets operator without allocating for string.

Comment: What error/bad output are you getting?

Comment: Avoid magic numbers as in `temp + 48`, and (wrong as I assume you use ASCII where `'A'` is `65`) `temp + 55`, `temp + '0'`, `temp + 'A'` is clearer (but not portable either `'A'`-`'Z'` is not guaranty to be contiguous). You might use portable `"0123456789ABCDEF"[temp]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You return always empty string. Your `hexaDeciNum`'s length is always 0. You need to change its size when to paste symbols there. By `hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 48;` you change the value of memory which not belongs to this string. `push_back()` will resize your your string and will add symbol at the end of the string. Change parts of code:

```
// check if temp < 10
if(temp < 10)
{
    hexaDeciNum.push_back(temp + 48);
    i++;
}
else
{
    hexaDeciNum.push_back(temp + 55);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your kind help. I am wondering how come I can print the characters in the for loop if the string is empty? Thanks `for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
        cout << hexaDeciNum[j] << "\n";`

Comment: @arcoxiatom You were writing to the memory which is out of string's memory, it doesn't belong to `hexaDeciNum`. You changed memory which doesn't belong to `hexaDeciNum`, that's bad. You could change something another important data. So you need to use `push_back()` to change its value in right way. There are some others ways too.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access indices of a string out of bounds.
If instead of printing `solution(word)` you try to print `solution(word).size()` you will get '0', because the string is still empty.

Try `hexaDeciNum.push_back(x)` when initializing the array. This will place the new character at the end of the current string.

Answer (score 0):

You're struggling from a lot of errors in your code. For starters the subscript operator you're using on `hexaDeciNum` is indexing out of bounds. Additionally you probably intended to allow `hexaDeciNum` to contain the characters 9 - 2 as well. If you add these checks you should see your output corrected.

---

The best solution here is to use the standard builtin features to solve this:

```
string solution(string &S){
    const auto n = stoi(S);
    const auto hexaDeciNum = static_cast<ostringstream&>(ostringstream() << hex << uppercase << n).str();

    return all_of(cbegin(hexaDeciNum), cend(hexaDeciNum), [](const unsigned char i){ return isxdigit(i); }) ? hexaDeciNum : "ERROR"s;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ovevJI)